# What are the pros and cons of running prod and dev on same openshift cluster

Tags: openshift

VMWare moved the focus from servers to VMs.  OpenShift moves the focus from VMs to applications (or so I've read).  With OpenShift is there any benefit in having separate clusters for dev and prod?  Should the CPU and memory resources provided by a cloud (Private, public, or hybrid) be treated as a single big pool when using OpenShift?

Comment: Comes down to personal preference. There is no technical reason why you can't run them in the same cluster. Using the one cluster allows better utilisation of underlying resources. Security teams though may want production entirely separate.

Comment: Also, having a separate production cluster forces you to think about how to represent your app as config and then automatically deploy it - that means in the future you can deploy the app to multiple clusters, or restore if from backup if something goes wrong, or have an automated test that creates the app from scratch each time.  Can do that on a single cluster, but having two forces you not to think of the cluster as special.